# My navbar sticks to the right edge of the page, when it stick to top on scroll

Tags: html, css

I have set my navbar to stick to the top on scroll down. But for some reason the div edge sticks to the edge of the page.

I have searched alot, but can't find anything, I just need it to be centered all the time...

```js
(function($) {
    "use strict";

    var $navbar = $("#navbar"), y_pos = $navbar.offset().top, height = $navbar.height();

    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (scrollTop > y_pos + height) {
            $navbar.addClass("navbar-fixed").animate({
                top: 0
            });
        } else if (scrollTop <= y_pos) {
            $navbar.removeClass("navbar-fixed").clearQueue().animate({
                top: "-48px"
            }, 0);
        }
    });
})
```

```css
/* nav stick to top*/
.navbar-fixed {
    top: 0;
    position: -webkit-fixed; /* Safari & IE */
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/*----------------------
  $NAVBAR
    basic navbar styling
  ----------------------*/
nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    color: #bbb;
    background-color: rgba(46, 46, 46, .6);
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.025em;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

nav ul {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
    transition: .1s ease;
    color: rgba(0,255,255,0.5);
    text-shadow: rgba(255, 0, 0, .8) -2.5px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-filter: blur(.2px);
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background: #156499;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
}
```

```html
</head>
    <header>
        <nav id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <a class="nav-btn" id="gotoGenRules_btn" href="#general-rules"><li>General Rules</li></a>
                <a class="nav-btn" id="gotoNLR_btn" href="#nlr"><li>NLR</li></a>
                <a class="nav-btn" id="gotoPropRules_btn" href="#prop-rules"><li>Prop Rules</li></a>
                <a class="nav-btn" id="gotoMisc_btn" href="#misc-rules"><li>Misc Rules</li></a>
                <a class="nav-btn" id="gotoPoliceRules_btn" href="#police-rules"><li>Police Rules</li></a>
                <a class="nav-btn" id="gotoRaidingRules_btn" href="#raiding-rules"><li>Raiding Rules</li></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
<body>
```

I want it to be in the middle of the screen all the time, but it just wanders off the the edge...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `left: 0;` in `.navbar-fixed` css will resolve your issue. Thanks

```
.navbar-fixed {
    top: 0;
    position: -webkit-fixed; /* Safari & IE */
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks! But now it stick to both edges, would u help me with that too?